# Right banner margin CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

On the site: [ukrainiansecret.com](http://ukrainiansecret.com)

I would like to get rid of that green right margin of the banner, and to have it exactly as the left side. Have tried to stretch the banner width but it didn't work out.

Thanks

Comment: Wich color do you want it , put more details in your question

Comment: Do you want the `div.banner_main` centered? Try adding a `margin:0 auto;` to the class.

Comment: I would like the banner image hide that green part. Thanks

Comment: Biotox, where exactly it has to be added? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way I did it was add a `width:100%;` to the `div.banner_main`, `ul#portfolio`, `ul#portfolio li` and `ul#portfolio li img` - that will make the image stretch all the way across the screen.

Example:

```
div.banner_main,
ul#portfolio,
ul#portfolio li,
ul#portfolio li img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: But your image is not all streched ?